# Exclude file in Brunch regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, brunch

I want to exclude a file mapdata.coffee inside the view folder in joinTo config of Brunch.

What I tried is

```
'javascripts/app.js':/^app(\/|\\)(?!(tests|store-test|views\/mapdata.coffee))/
```

Where am I missing?

Comment: This does not allow `app/tests` or `app/views/.mapdata.coffee`, but would allow `app/anything/views/.mapdata.coffee`. Is that what you intend?

Comment: I want that `mapdata.coffee` should not be included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it should work, unless you're on a Windows system using backslashes as the path separator. In which case

```
/^app[\\\/](?!(tests|store-test|views[\\\/]mapdata.coffee))/
```

ought to work.

In a node REPL:

```
> /^app(\/|\\)(?!(tests|store-test|views\/mapdata.coffee))/.test('app/views/mapdata.coffee')
false
> /^app(\/|\\)(?!(tests|store-test|views\/mapdata.coffee))/.test('app\\views\\mapdata.coffee')
true
> /^app[\\\/](?!(tests|store-test|views[\\\/]mapdata.coffee))/.test('app\\views\\mapdata.coffee')
false
> /^app[\\\/](?!(tests|store-test|views[\\\/]mapdata.coffee))/.test('app\\views\\foo.coffee')
true
```

You can also define your `joinTo`s with things other than regexes. Take a look at the [anymatch documentation](https://github.com/es128/anymatch).